# pentaho set variable to jobs

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to pentaho. I have a Job with 3 transformation and all 3 transformation are simliar . In each transformation has Sql query  something like
`select * from table1 where tabl1.col1='XXX' and tab2.col2='YYYY'`

value of col1 remains same.  I want to pass it as variable in job instead of replacing it in each transformation .  What are the steps to do that.

Comment: you have to first set the variables in 1st transformation and in other transformation you have to get the variables.
I will suggest to read of set variables and get variables concept.

Comment: There's a difference between variables and field substitution. Is it the table input step?

Answer (score 1):

you split your transformation in two:

1. one for setting the var
2. the second for using set variable from step #1.

Please refer to Pentaho Documentation available online :

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Using+Variables+in+Kettle

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Set+Variables

You cannot use variables in the same transformation where you set them.